# replacing custom keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I'm trying to create my own keyboard for iPhone and trying to replace the default one.

There are a lot of custom keyboards in Cydia that replaces default one

so it is definately possible.

my question is

How can I create the keyboard

this would not use iOS APIs

is there any sample sources or other things that I can look around?

Comment: do you want to customize keyboard?

Comment: @user2621772 - You can have a look at this custom control https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards - how it functions internally

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could change default keyboard. and If you anyhow modify it(using private methods) apple will reject your app because it is against apple guidelines.

So the only solution to your problem is create a custom keyboard and then use it. There are few custom keyboards you can use them also :

[custom-ios-keyboards](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/custom-ios-keyboards)

[ioscustomkb](http://thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/63-ioscustomkb.html)

[how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-with-custom-navigation-buttons](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-with-custom-navigation-buttons)

Hope it helps you.